# Can we send a memory stream object with web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, memorystream

I have one memory stream object in my server-side, this object should be accessible in another party, which I call it a client or a consumer for my API.
In server-side I have a method like this (parameters.Save is related to a third-party library)

```
    public MemoryStream GetSerializedParameters()
    {
        var parameters = GetParameters();
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        parameters.Save(memory);
        return memory;
    }
```

I'm thinking about sending this memory stream to a client with web API, so my action is something like this:

```
[HttpGet("parameters")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetParameters()
    {
        var stream = _server.GetSerializedParameters();
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        return result;
    }
```

I'm not sure if it is the right way and this implementation is correct because I am in trouble to consume it:
I do not know which method of httpClient I have to use: `ReadAsStreamAsync()` or anything else, because I could not find anything to work

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution like this:
here is in server side:

```
    [HttpGet("parameters")]
    public IActionResult GetParameters()
    {
        var stream = _server.GetSerializedParameters();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(stream, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, "parameters.txt");
    }
```

and here is in client-side:

```
        public MemoryStream StoreParameters()
    {
        var request =new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44316/api/parameters"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var result = _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        result.Content.CopyToAsync(ms).Wait();
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode ? ms: null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            var randomString = "thisIsCool";
            var randomStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(randomString);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(randomStringBytes))
            {
                await ms.CopyToAsync(this.Response.Body);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my under standing below code may help you:

**WEB API:**

```
        [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReadToStream(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
       
            var streamObj = _server.GetSerializedParameters();
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StreamContent(streamObj);
            requestMessage.RegisterForDispose(streamObj);
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return response;
   }
```

**Client Side**

```
public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string guid)
{
var fileInfo = new FileInfo($"{guid}.txt");

var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{url}/api/fileDownloadAPI?guid={guid}");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
await using var ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
await using var fs = File.Create(fileInfo.FullName);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ms.CopyTo(fs);
return fileInfo.FullName;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but streamObj is MemoryStream object which it does not have OutputStream property.

Comment: Updated code. Basically in my case I was returning a custom object and whose property was Outputstream. So here we can directly use streamObj.

Comment: ok, Thanks. is there any way to store the file in memory stream instead of the file stream on the client-side?

Comment: Sorry, I did't get you. Do you mean instead of saving file on disk on webserver, can we store as Memory stream? Could you please explain your requirement?

Comment: Thanks, Vikas for your effort, I found the solution.

Comment: Hi, @someone, you could share your solution and finish the issue for helping more developer.

Comment: @MichaelWang, yes, sure.